# how to access root file like /data/data/a.log in a rooted android device programmatically?

Tags: android, root, privileges

This seems not working anymore in android 9.
Is there any Java programmatically way to access a root file ?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su",
                        "mount -o rw,remount /system",
                        "chmod 777 /data/data/com.xx/a.log" ,
                        "mount -o ro,remount /system"
                }).waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

App can programmatic access any inner storage files in /data/data/app-inner-dir, but app itself still can not access files outside the app-inner-dir, even if it's granted root permission. To make that happen, we can create a link to the target file inside app-inner-dir, then change its access permission.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su root ln [target-file-path] [/data/data/app-inner-dir/file]").waitFor();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su root chmod o+r [/data/data/app-inner-dir/file]").waitFor();
```

After doing that, app can programmatic access the file directly.